# Assembly Adding and Subtracting Numbers

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am writing a program in Assembly and I am having the issue of adding 2 numbers that total over 10. For instance when I add 5 and 5 (after converting to Decimal) I get 000A, which is obviously the ASCII for new line. So I want to convert it to 10. The idea I had would be to add a -10 to bring it back down to single digit, then add a digit 10 back on. When I add a -10 I get the total of FFFA instead of a decimal number. I am not sure why 5 + 5 is A, but A - 5 would not be 5 again.

```
ADD    R0, R0, #5
ADD    R0, R0, #5      ; results in 000A being in R0
ADD    R4, R4, #-10
ADD    R1, R0, R4      ; results in FFFA instead of 0000
```

Comment: `A` is the correct result (in hex). If you need to print it, you should conditionally print a leading `1` and only then subtract 10. The condition being `result > 9` of course.

Comment: The sixteen hex digits are: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F` and after that the double-digit numbers go `10 11 ... 1E 1F` and so on. It is irrelevant that `0xA` is the ASCII `newline` character.

Comment: Hexadecimal digits are a convenient way to express a binary number, in groups of four bits. The binary number `01000010` is easier for many people to understand when expressed as hex `42`. Larger numbers, even more so.

Comment: What did the registers contain before your operations?